# Element is detected, but not clicking

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need help.
    I was able to locate the Element but it is not clicking 
    I had to use action class because .click() method gave me no point element error in selenium.

```
Teams click = new Teams (driver);
Actions cl = new Actions (driver);
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement x = click.teamsClick();
x=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(click.teamsClick()));
cl.moveToElement(click.teamsClick()).click().perform();
```

Comment: Please post the `.teamsClick()` method. `.click()` methods typically don't return anything. Also, post the full exception you were getting when you tried to do a regular click.

Answer (score 1):

It can simply work by,

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement("element name").click().perform();
```

Comment: @Syed Alam, Have you tried ? If it works, Please accept answer by voting.